# d3js stack chart：how to get y coordinate of some x?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In the example of [Stacked Area via Nest](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3020685), its `CSV` data is :

```
Group1,37,04/23/12
Group1,32,04/24/12
Group1,45,04/25/12
Group1,24,04/26/12
```

[image]

Suppose that the x'axis is continuous, and let `svg`'s height is `h`, `svg`'s width is `w`.

As shown in the figure above, given the `x` coordinate, how to get the **group1's** height(or thickness) on such `x` ?

My final requirement is : given a point `(x, y)` inside of the `svg`, how can I determine that which group it belongs to ?

Comment: Call getPointAtLength on the path (start with a distance of getTotalLength()/2). Binary chop the distance till the x value is as desired, read off the y value.

Comment: My final requirement is : given a point `(x, y)` inside of the `svg`, how can I determine that which `group` it belongs to ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint